# Como deletar registos de varias tabelas ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: mysql, sql

Quero dar *delete* num aluno para isso quero eliminar os registos desse mesmo aluno de todas as tabelas onde ele está e a sua imagem da pasta onde está foi guarda para isso utilizo o seguinte código :

```
<?php
    /* 
     * Verifica se a variável com o id do aluno está definida
     * Se não estiver volta à página inicial
     */
    if (!isset ($_GET['idc']))
        print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=menuadmin.php?id=4'>";

    // Pega no registo selecionado para saber o nome 
    // da imagem ($al_img) para depois a eliminar
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Aluno WHERE al_id = ".$_GET['idc'];
    $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)!= 0){ 
        $registo = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
        extract($registo);

        //Elimina a imagem
        unlink("imagens/aluno/".$al_img);
        }

    /* Elimina o registo */
    mysql_query("DELETE FROM Inscricao, 
                             Aluno, 
                             EncarregadoDeEducacao, 
                             Musica_Aluno, 
                             OutrasAtividades_Aluno, 
                             Explicacoes_Aluno, 
                             Psicologia_Aluno, 
                             SalaDeEstudo_Aluno  
                 WHERE 
                             Inscricao.al_id = Aluno.al_id AND 
                             EncarregadoDeEducacao.ee_id = Inscricao.ee_id AND 
                             Musica_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                             OutrasAtividades_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND
                             Explicacoes_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                             Psicologia_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                             SalaDeEstudo_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                             Inscricao.al_id = ".$_GET['idc'])

    echo mysql_error();
    /* Verifica se deu erro ao eliminar o registo */ 
    if (mysql_error()){
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>";
        echo 'alert ("Erro ao eliminar ao aluno...");';
        echo "</script>";
    }

    /* Volta à página inicial */ 
    print "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='Refresh' CONTENT='0;URL=menuadmin.php?id=4'>";


?>
```

O erro que me da é o seguinte :

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\estagio\eliminaraluno.php on line 32

Qual o problema no código?

--------EDITADO : ------

já coloquei o `;` agora já da mas da-me este error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Inscricao.al_id = Aluno.al_id AND Encarregad' at line 1
```

Comment: Possivelmente é por causa da falta do `;` após o método `mysql_query()`.

Comment: é bem provável que seja a falta do ponto e virgula no final da função mysql_query();

Comment: de uma olhada no comando ON DELETE CASCADE do mysql poderia ser muito util nessa situação

Comment: já coloquei o `;` agora já da mas da-me este error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE Inscricao.al_id = Aluno.al_id AND Encarregad' at line 1

Comment: Coloca ON DELETE CASCADE nas fK's

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/734610/1817673

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você tem que especificar de quais as tabelas quer deletar, você só informou as tabelas de relacionamento. Tente colocar as tabelas entre o `DELETE` e o `FROM`, assim:

```
mysql_query("DELETE 
                             Inscricao.*, 
                             Aluno.*, 
                             EncarregadoDeEducacao.*, 
                             Musica_Aluno.*, 
                             OutrasAtividades_Aluno.*, 
                             Explicacoes_Aluno.*, 
                             Psicologia_Aluno.*, 
                             SalaDeEstudo_Aluno.*
                FROM         Inscricao, 
                             Aluno, 
                             EncarregadoDeEducacao, 
                             Musica_Aluno, 
                             OutrasAtividades_Aluno, 
                             Explicacoes_Aluno, 
                             Psicologia_Aluno, 
                             SalaDeEstudo_Aluno  
                 WHERE 
                             Inscricao.al_id = Aluno.al_id AND 
                             EncarregadoDeEducacao.ee_id = Inscricao.ee_id AND 
                             Musica_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                             OutrasAtividades_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND
                             Explicacoes_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                             Psicologia_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                             SalaDeEstudo_Aluno.al_id = Inscricao.al_id AND 
                             Inscricao.al_id = ".$_GET['idc'])
```

Outra forma de fazer é adicionar chave externa em todas as tabelas com o `DELETE = CASCADE`.

Comment: dessa forma não da erro mas não elimina os registos da base de dados.

Comment: Dessa forma funciona, más você pode colocar um ".*" na frente das tabelas. Corrigi minha resposta dessa forma.

Comment: Se não deletar nenhum registro, é porque você está com algum problema no relacionamento entre as tabelas. Refaça o SQL trocando o DELETE por SELECT e veja se retorna algum resultado.